# Difference between Pointers in C# and C

Tags: c#

i have this code in c:

```
long data1 = 1091230456;
*(double*)&((data1)) = 219999.02343875566
```

when i use the same code in C# the result is:

```
*(double*)&((data1)) = 5.39139480005278E-315
```

but if i define another varibale in C# :

```
unsafe 
{long *data2 = &(data1);}
```

now :

```
*(double)&((data2)) = 219999.02343875566
```

Why the difference ?

Comment: i mean this code:   *(double*)&((data1))

Comment: You can [edit] your question to improve it, rather than trying to comment - but I think Soner's edit is correct (note the use of code blocks, by indenting four spaces or highlighting the block and hitting `{}` allows us to see literal code)

Comment: long can be 32 bits for C but is always 64 bits for C#. It depends on your C compiler

Comment: @thumbmunkeys - I think that's an answer.

Comment: possibly you should use [`fixed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(v=vs.120).aspx) keyword

Comment: @Grundy what does it have to do with fixed keyword? This result is reproducible on stack.

Comment: @Grundy No, that doesn't have a use for value-typed locals - they're already "fixed" by being on the stack / in a register.

Comment: why if i write : unsafe
{
 long *data2 = &(data1);
} 

 *(double*)&((data2)) = 219999.02343875566

Comment: @rinat if you have another question, please edit your existing one or post another question

Comment: @rinat: `long data2 = &(data1)` doesn't make sense since `data1` is `long` so `&data1` is clearly not going to be a long...

Comment: sorry it is: long* data2 = &(data1)

Comment: That is now telling me I `Cannot convert type 'long**' to 'double'`. Perhaps you should write a short but complete program (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) to demonstrate this. Then you can be sure that what others are running and seeing should be exactly what you are. Use `Console.WriteLine` to output the values you are questioning at appropriate points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting pointers is always tricky, especially when you don't have guarantees about the layout and size of the underlying types.

In C#, `long` is always a 64-bit integer and `double` is always 64-bit floating point number.

In C, `long` can easily end up being smaller than the 64-bits needed. If you're using a compiler that translates `long` as a 32-bit number, the rest of the value will be junk read from the next piece of memory - basically a "buffer" overflow.

On Windows, you usually want to use `long long` for 64-bit integers. Or better, use something like `int64_t`, where you're guaranteed to have exactly 64-bits of data. Or the best, *don't cast pointers*.

C integer types can be confusing if you have a Java / C# background. They give you guarantees about the minimal range they must allow, but that's it. For example, `int` must be able to hold values in the `[−32767,+32767]` range (note that it's not `-32768` - C had to support one's complement machines, which had two zeroes), close to C#'s `short`. `long` must be able to hold values in the `[−2147483647,+2147483647]` range, close to C#'s `int`. Finally, `long long` is close to C#'s `long`, having at least the `[-2^63,+2^63]` range. `float` and `double` are specified even more loosely.

Whenever you cast pointers, you throw away even the tiny bits of abstraction C provides you with - you work with the underlying hardware layouts, whatever those are. This is one road to hell and something to avoid.

Sure, these days you probably will not find one's complement numbers, or other floating points than IEEE 754, but it's still inherently unsafe and unpredictable.

**EDIT:**

Okay, reproducing your example fully in a way that actually compiles:

```
unsafe 
{
  long data1 = 1091230456;
  long *data2 = &data1;

  var result = *(double*)&((data2));
}
```

`result` ends up being `219999.002675845` for me, close enough to make it obvious. Let's see what you're actually doing here, in more detail:

1. Store 1091230456 in a local `data1`
2. Take the address of `data1`, and store it in `data2`
3. Take the address of `data2`, cast it to a `double` pointer
4. Take the double value of the resulting pointer

It should be obvious that whatever value ends up in `result` has little relation to the value you stored in `data1` in the first place!

Printing out the various parts of what you're doing will make this clearer:

```
unsafe 
{
    long data1 = 1091230456;
    long *pData1 = &data1;

    var pData2 = &pData1;
    var pData2Double = (double*)pData2;
    var result = *pData2Double;

    new 
    {
      data1 = data1,
      pData1 = (long)pData1,
      pData2 = (long)pData2,
      pData2Double = (long)pData2Double,
      result = result
    }.Dump();
}
```

This prints out:

```
data1: 1091230456 
pData1: 91941328 
pData2: 91941324 
pData2Double: 91941324 
result: 219999.002675845
```

This will vary according to many environmental settings, but the critical part is that `pData2` is pointing to memory four bytes *in front of* the actual data! This is because of the way the locals are allocated on stack - `pData2` is pointing to `pData1`, not to `data1`. Since we're using 32-bit pointers here, we're reading the last four bytes of the original `long`, combined with the stack pointer to `data1`. You're reading at the wrong address, skipping over one indirection. To get back to the correct result, you can do something like this:

```
var pData2Double = (double**)pData2;
var result = *(*pData2Double);
```

This results in `5.39139480005278E-315` - the original value produced by your C# code. This is the more "correct" value, as far as there can even be a correct value.

The obvious answer here is that your C code is wrong as well - either due to different operand semantics, or due to some bug in the code you're not showing (or again, using a 32-bit integer instead of 64-bit), you end up with a pointer to a pointer to the value you want, and you mistakenly build the resulting `double` on a scrambled value that includes part of the original `long`, as well as the stack pointer - in other words, exactly one of the reasons you should be extra cautious whenever using `unsafe` code. Interestingly, this also implies that when compiled as a 64-bit executable, the result will be entirely decoupled from the value of `data1` - you'll have a `double` built on the stack pointer exclusively.

**Don't mess with pointers** until you understand indirection very, very well. They have a tendency to "mostly work" when used *entirely wrong*. Then you change a tiny part of the code (for example, in this code you could add a third local, which could change where `pData1` is allocated) or move to a different architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit is quite enough in this example), or a different compiler, or a different OS... and it breaks completely. You don't *guess* around your way with pointers. Either you know exactly what every single expression in the code means, or you shouldn't deal with pointers at all.

Comment: hi , thank you for your answer
but why if i write : unsafe
{
 long *data2 = &(data1);
} 

 *(double*)&((data2)) = 219999.02343875566

Comment: @rinat: which language are you writing that in? It doesn't look like it should compile in c# (since data2 isn't a long) but I didn't think C had a concept of "unsafe"... It occurs to me that line may have lost some context due to interpretation of characters as markup. Use backticks around text to make them as code. That is ` character.

Comment: hi chris, thanks
 i write in C#: 
unsafe
{
 long *data2 = &(data1);
} 
and with visual studio watch(in C#) i see that : *(double*)&((data2)) = 219999.02343875566 
and *(double*)&((data1)) = 5.39139480005278E-315

Comment: @rinat That still doesn't compile. What is the code you're using *exactly*?

Comment: Hi luaan, thank you for your answer.but can you please tell me how can i get the same results in c in c# as well? what should i change to get the same results?  maybe i get this because of endian swap?

Comment: @rinat No, because the results in your C application are based on undefined behaviour - you're casting a pointer that's pointing to a 32-bit structure to a pointer pointing to a 64-bit structure. Your C application is wrong, plain and simple. When you fix it (if your code sample is exact, all you need to do is change `long` to `int64_t` or `long long` everywhere), the C# version will agree with the results.